# android share to Facebook wall with Bundle

Tags: android, facebook, bundle, android-facebook

I try to share Facebook wall some text with bundle. i wrote some code .i can share to Facebook but i have problem
this is a my source

```
public void callFacebook(final String title) {
    android.util.Log.i("FB", "callFacebook");
    fb.authorize(MainActivity.this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final Bundle values) {
            android.util.Log.i("#### FB", "onComplete");



                android.util.Log.i("#### FB", "not post_id");
                try {
                    final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("message", "this is a test");
                    final String FacebookUrl = "https://google.com";

                    parameters.putString("name", title);
                    parameters.putString("link", FacebookUrl);
                    fb.dialog(MainActivity.this, "stream.publish", parameters,
                            this);

                } catch (final Exception e) {

                    android.util.Log.i("#### FB", e.getMessage());
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(final FacebookError error) {
            android.util.Log.i("#### FB", "FacebookError: " + error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final DialogError e) {
            android.util.Log.i("#### FB", "DialogError: " + e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            android.util.Log.i("#### FB", "cancel");

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

as i said i can share to Facebook  but when i click share and text has shared window does not close automaticly
i mean this window[image] when i click cancel button  also can't close window
what is a wrong in my code if anyone knows solution please help me

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has deprecated stream.publish dialog for years. Instead "stream.publish", "feed" is something you can try.  However, "feed" is no longer a recommended one based on the document.

It is always easy to build a suggested sharing experience by following the doc:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Comment: Maybe summarise what the doc says so people can see what you mean